# Why overridePendingTransition not work in android 4.0 or above version?

Tags: android

This code work well in my HTC Disire and Android 2.3.3 device,but not work in my android 4.0 phone——Huawei C8812?

```
public void changeNextActivity(Class<?> c){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,c);
    this.startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_right_in,R.anim.animation_left_out);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try writing the overridePendingTransition code in the onCreate of the new activity.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_hor, R.anim.slide_out_hor);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
```